# How to find the count of documents of a collection based on the search criteria of other collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've 2 collections which are connected to each other. Now I want to find the count of documents of 1st collections based on the search criteria of 2nd collection. I have a status field in 1st collection for which it has a reference in the 2nd collection. Now how can I find the documents count whose status is COMPLETED?

```
//CaseReport model//
var reportSchema=new Schema({
    caseType_id     : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DropDowns'},
    description     : String,
    caseStatus      : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DropDowns'});
var CaseReports=mongoose.model('CaseReports',reportSchema);

//Dropdowns model//
var dropdownSchema=new Schema({
    dropdown_name   : {type: String, unique: true},
    type            : {type: String, ref: 'CaseReports'},
    status          : {type: Boolean, default: true, ref: 'CaseReports'});
var DropDowns=mongoose.model('DropDowns',dropdownSchema);
```

Comment: can you tell me what exactly be the search criteria? and can you show some sample document from your collection?